# remove style from class on one page only?

Tags: css, wordpress, class, styles, border

I need to remove the `border-top: 1px solid #202020;` from `.contact` on [my contact page](http://www.frshstudio.com/contact/) only, and leave as is in all other `.contact` instances. Is this possible? If so, how do I make these changes?

Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you just give it a seperate class?

Comment: Can't you assign a another class to that element?

Comment: Could be a dynamic include or the like, it's not always possible to change it just for one page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give that page's body a special class like

```
<body class="contact-page">
```

Then in your css

```
body.contact-page .contact{
    border-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to body or other wrapper tag like `<body class="contacts-page">`

Then use the following CSS `.contacts-page .contact { border-top: none }`

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to your http://frshstudio.com/wp-content/themes/frsh/style.css file:

```
.contact_contact{border-top: none;}
```

and your html:

```
<div class="contact contact_contact">
  <p>
    <span>Let's Chat</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always override stylesheet css with inline css. So like all the other people suggested, put .contact { border-top: none; } but do it like this

```
<head>
      <style>
       .contact { border-top: none; }
      </style>
</head>
```

This will only disable the border on your page while all your other pages will obey the stylesheet.